# Sorting in react sorts in every component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am having an issue where when I sort in react it applys that sorting across the entire app.

I have a main component that calls an api and then the data is placed into a state. That state then is passed into graph component. Then on the graph component page I sort it with the props passed.

It should only apply on that component on those props shouldn't it ?

```
<Total_active_today data={this.state.dataset.sort(function(a,b){
     return parseInt(b.active_today)  - parseInt(a.active_today);
}).slice(0, 20)} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Array `sort` method mutates the array on which it's called. Make a shallow copy before you sort and you should be okay!

```
<Total_active_today data={[...this.state.dataset].sort(function(a,b){
     return parseInt(b.active_today)  - parseInt(a.active_today);
}).slice(0, 20)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// sort data
const [sorted, setSorted] = useState({sorted: "price", reversed: false});
const sortByPrice = () => {
    setSorted({sorted: "price", reversed: !sorted.reversed});
    const datacopy = [...data];
    datacopy.sort((a, b) => {
        if (sorted.reversed) {
            return b.price - a.price;
        }
        return a.price - b.price;
    });
    setData(datacopy);
};

<button onClick={sortByPrice}>Sort data</button>
```

---

```
//search data

const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

{
    data && data.filter((product) => {
        return search.trim().toLowerCase() === ""
            ? product
            : product.name.toLowerCase().includes(search);
    })
}

<input type="search" onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).